# Speed up read.dbf in R (problems with importing large dbf file)

Tags: r, foxpro, dbf

I have a dataset given in .dbf format and need to import it into R.
I haven't worked with such extension previously, so have no idea how to export dbf file with multiple tables into different format.

Simple read.dbf has been running hours and still no results.
Tried to look for speeding up R performance, but not sure whether it's the case, think the problem is behind reading the large dbf file itself (weights ~ 1.5Gb), i.e. the command itself must be not efficient at all. However, I don't know any other option how to deal with such dataset format.
Is there any other option to import the dbf file?

P.S. (NOT R ISSUE) The source of the dbf file uses visual foxpro, but can't export it to other format. I've installed foxpro, but given that I've never used it before, I don't know how to export it in the right way. Tried simple "Export to type=XLS" command, but here comes a problem with encoding as most of variables are in Russian Cyrillic and can't be decrypted by excel. In addition, the dbf file contains multiple tables that should be merged in 1 big table, but I don't know how to export those tables separately to xls, same as I don't know how to export multiple tables as a whole into xls or csv, or how to merge them together as I'm absolutely new to dbf files theme (though looked through base descriptions already)

Any helps will be highly appreciated. Not sure whether I can provide with sample dataset, as there are many columns when I look the dbf in foxpro, plus those columns must be merged with other tables from the same dbf file, and have no idea how to do that. (sorry for the mess)

Comment: Which package are you using? `foreign`?

Comment: It might be easier to export each table to csv separately, and then read them into R. I haven't used Foxpro, but there should be an "export table" command or similar on the File menu.

Comment: another thing to try might be `maptools:::dbf.read` but there are many more options if you can get your data in CSV format. I find `data.table::fread` to be very fast when reading large CSV files

Comment: Yes, used foreign. Tried once maptools, didn't help.

@Hong Ooi, thanks, managed to export tables manually, but then there comes a problem with encoding. In addition data.table::fread returns exception "Expected sep (',') but '"' ends field" for the most of exported files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can export from Visual FoxPro in many formats using the COPY TO command via the Command Window, as per the VFP help file.

For example:

```
use mydbf in 0
select mydbf
copy to myfile.xls type xl5
copy to myfile.csv type delimited
```

If you're having language-related issues, you can add an 'as codepage' clause to the end of those. For example:

```
copy to myfile.csv type delimited as codepage 1251
```

If you are not familiar with VFP I would try to get the raw data out like that, and into a platform that you *are* familiar with, before attempting merges etc.

To export them in a loop you could use the following in a .PRG file (amending the two path variables at the top to reflect your own setup).

```
    Close All
Clear All
Clear 

lcDBFDir = "c:\temp\"           && -- Where the DBF files are.
lcOutDir = "c:\temp\export\"        && -- Where you want your exported files to go.

lcDBFDir = Addbs(lcDBFDir)      && -- In case you forgot the backslash.
lcOutDir = Addbs(lcOutDir)  

* -- Get the filenames into an array.
lnFiles = ADir(laFiles, Addbs(lcDBFDir) + "*.DBF")

* -- Process them. 
For x = 1 to lnFiles

    lcThisDBF = lcDBFDir + laFiles[x, 1]
    Use (lcThisDBF) In 0 Alias currentfile
    Select currentfile
    Copy To (lcOutDir + Juststem(lcThisDBF) + ".csv") type csv
    Use in Select("Currentfile")        && -- Close it.

EndFor

Close All
```

... and run it from the Command Window - Do myprg.prg or whatever.

Comment: +1!Maybe you should mention how/where she can run this commands.(In programs I guess..)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is there any options to get a list of all tables contained in the dbf? And export them all in a loop? :)

Comment: Nomenclature here is slightly different than what you might assume coming from database servers like MSSQL, PostGres etc. - DBF files *are* discrete tables. They may or may not belong to a database container which is the 'database' (has a .DBC extension). If they do, you can open the database container with OPEN DATABASE and then LIST TABLES TO mylist.txt.

Comment: You would run the copy to commands, or indeed almost any other command, in the Command Window.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  
As far as I understood, this code read all dbf files in the specified folder (which I also need as have several similar files). Just awesome! But I also need to export all tables within that one dbf file, as 1 file contains multiple tables. There is 1 big table that has about 100 columns, which variables are coded, and about 100 other tables that have explanation of those codes (so I need to merge them in final version to have 'readable' dataset). Now I can do it only manually by selecting File->Export (as @Hong Ooi pointed out)

Comment: As I said, DBF files are discrete tables. They do not have other tables within them.

Comment: Sorry, just got it right now! (haven't used foxpro before, sorry)
Again, thank you very much!!!